# Information in gdalinfo not shown

Tags: geoserver, gdal, gdalinfo

I have a geotiff and I checked it's metadata using gdalinfo.exe:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: C:/image_test.tif
Size is 3956, 34151
Coordinate System is `'
GCP Projection = 
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
          (1,1) -> (119.851499142389,-30.7134418800722,390.999576434493)
GCP[  1]: Id=2, Info=
          (3956,1) -> (119.352774909547,-30.6076899722145,390.999578144401)
GCP[  2]: Id=3, Info=
          (1,34151) -> (118.788734486763,-34.4555300913518,390.99952176027)
GCP[  3]: Id=4, Info=
          (3956,34151) -> (118.265259471947,-34.3453414924152,390.999523188919)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2019:04:07 13:55:02
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=3 (pixels/cm)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=0.00079999998
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=0.00079999998
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,34151.0)
Upper Right ( 3956.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 3956.0,34151.0)
Center      ( 1978.0,17075.5)
Band 1 Block=3956x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

I am trying to create an ImageMosaic in geoserver but the corner coordinates are just the pixel ranges and not the actual lat/longs and so the WMS layer is abit crazy.

I've looked at other geotiff's that work and they include within the coordinate system, e.g.:

```
Origin = (-70.119788596117274,18.999683535544683)
Pixel Size = (0.000256210858208,-0.000256210858208)
```

Is there a way I can set this and then also apply this to the corner coordinates? Maybe using gdal_transform.exe?

Answer (score 3):

What you did does edit the bounds but by the same you have destroyed the georeferencing. The original image is georeferenced with 4 ground control points and if you look at the coordinates you will notice that the image was not north-up but rotated/skewed. The right thing to do is to warp the image into a north-up image with gdalwarp

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg.4326 image_test.tif warped_into_north_up.tif
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I used the `-a_srs` argument in `gdal_transform` and supplied minimum/maximum lat/longs.

This Assigns/override the georeferenced bounds of the output file.